# Apache Set MIME Type Dynamically

Tags: apache

We have mutiple files where we need to set MIME type based upon file type. Ex:

```
/{path}/alpha.woff --> font/woff
/{path}/beta.woff2 --> font/woff2
/{path}/gamma.ttf --> font/ttf
```

We have added the below snippet in apache config file but not certain how to achieve with one LocationMatch attribute

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?i:woff|woff2|ttf)$">
        Header set Content-Type font/{dynamically set woff OR woff2 OR ttf }
</LocationMatch>
```

This can be done with multiple LocationMatch (one for each font) but looks not optimized one.
Can anyone suggest better solution to deal with such situation?

Tried with regex which throw an error.

```
 <LocationMatch "\.(?<fonttype>(?i:woff|woff2|ttf))$">
   Header set Content-Type font/woff // Work fine but set font/woff for all fonts
 </LocationMatch>
```

Below throw error in config

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?<fonttype>(?i:woff|woff2|ttf))$">
   Header set Content-Type font/%{env:MATCH_FONTTYPE}
 </LocationMatch>
```

Unrecognized header format %

Answer (score 0):

The mime types can be configured in the `conf/mime.types` configuration file of the Apache HTTP Server, see the example [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types):

```
font/woff                                       woff
font/woff2                                      woff2
font/ttf                                        ttf
```

If you can't update this file, and `LocationMatch` directive is your only option, then starting from Apache 2.4.8 you can use named regex capture groups, see [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch).

In the following example, I've named the capture group `fonttype`, so by convention it will be put into the environment variable `MATCH_FONTTYPE`. This environment variable can be used in the `ForceType` expression:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?<fonttype>(?i:woff|woff2|ttf))$">
    ForceType font/%{env:MATCH_FONTTYPE}
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks, So below should work I believe.

<LocationMatch "\.(?i:woff|woff2|ttf)$">
    ForceType font/woff woff
 ForceType font/woff2 woff2
 ForceType font/ttf ttf
</LocationMatch>

Comment: Not quite what I meant. You don‘t even need the LocationMatch configuration for serving static files, it should be enough to set the types in mime.types

Comment: Actually we don't have that config file and not have control to create one, we have vhosts files to update only. So anything we can configure in that is feasible.
Currently fonts are rendering different mime types

Comment: @VivekDhiman then you could use named capture groups in the regular expression, I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Hi I tried that snippet but its not changing the content type. However Header set Content-Type works, but with regex it throw error. I have updated the Question.

Comment: This might be those named capture groups are only applicable to version > 2.4.
Is there way to achieve this in 2.2?

Comment: Yes, this syntax is available since 2.4.8. With 2.2 your only option is to repeat several sections for each extension.